# Pandas: how to aggregate data by some column's value sum or by row count?

Tags: python, pandas

I have Pandas dataframe which is as simple as:

```
>columnA
>>1
>>20
>>3
>>4
>>15
>>0
```

I want to aggregate this dataframe in two ways:

1. simply aggregate by number of rows: for example sum columnA values for each 3 rows. I.e. after this transformation I should get

   ```
   aggregatedByCount
   24
   19
   ```
2. aggregate when sum of values in columnA exceeds some threshold, for example 10. I.e. after this I should get

   ```
      aggregatedBySum 
         21 
         22
   ```

Is it possible to implement this without loops?

Answer (score 0):

**First Option**

```
df.groupby(df.index // 3).sum()

        columnA
    0       24
    1       19
```

**Second Option** cumsum twice to partition threshold and to set new groups after threshold is established.

```
  df['groups']=(df.groupby(df.index ).cumsum()>10)
df.groupby(df['groups'].shift().fillna(True)\
.cumsum()).columnA.sum()[lambda x: x >10]


  groups
1    21
2    22
```

Answer (score -1):

To sum by every three rows:

```
out1 = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 3).sum()
```

For your second request:

```
c = 0
g = 0
limit = 10
grouper = []
for val in df.columnA:
    c += val
    grouper.append(g)
    if c > 10:
        c = 0
        g += 1

out2 = df.groupby(grouper).sum()
```

Output

```
   columnA
0       21
1       22
2        0
```

Comment: @MiamiBeach did you try it?